# Edge slide + copy

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

How can you do a simultaneous edge copy and slide; in the image:

[image]

hoe can the selected edge be duplicated and slid to the front so that I have a face with 4 vertices?

Comment: can you first add a loop cut, and then slide that?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I can only add loop cuts to faces made up from an even number of vertexes.

Comment: What I would do is delete the two problematic faces, select that edge and the one next to it, extrude, and align it with vertex snapping. Then remove doubles. Not technically what you're asking to do but it would solve the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem.
Just use the *Rip and Fill function*

*Vertex > Rip Vertices and Fill*
Shortcut: <kbd>Alt+V</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks; but let's say you merge vertexes by distance to the left and now one face is made out of three vertexes two to the center right and one the the left. How can you stretch out the vertex to left so that you don't have problems with modifiers?

Comment: Hey :). Sorry, I didn't check the image properly. Answer edited with an appropriate solution.